# How do I setup the views for nested resources that are displayed as tabs within their parent resource in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-resources

I have a resource `Company` that has many `Projects` and `People`. The `index` action for the companies displays each company in a table. The `show` action shows some additional information about it, and then what I'd like to show is another table, with tabs "Projects" and "People".

When I click on the "People" tab, I should go to URL "companies/:id/people", and likewise for the "Projects" tab. I'm not worried about AJAX or pre-loading all of this information into the `@company` variable during the `show` action. A simple nested resource is fine.

Now when I'm at "companies/:id/people", it will use `PeopleController#index`, but I want to show that view (which is JUST it's table, I suppose?) nested within the company's `show` view. So that when I switch between "companies/:id/people" and "companies/:id/projects", the only thing changing is the table, not the company information around the outside.

Is this sort of thing easily do-able? If Rails isn't build to handle this sort of thing easily, I don't mind using something else. I just don't have much experience with the view layer, so I don't know much about it since I primarily work with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic Example:**

ProjectsController && PeopleController:

```
layout :current_layout

def current_layout
  if @company && @company.persisted? && request.path_parameters[:action] == "index" # i prefer helper 'current_action'
    "company"
  else
    "application"
  end
end
```

Helper:

```
def parent_layout(layout)
  @view_flow.set(:layout, self.output_buffer)
  self.output_buffer = render(:file => "layouts/#{layout}")
end
```

Company layout:

```
#views/layouts/company.html.erb

<h1><%= @company %></h1>
<ul class="tabs">
 <li>Info</li>
 <li>Info</li>
 <li>Info</li>
</ul>
<%= yield %>
<%= parent_layout(:application) %>
```

People template:

```
# views/people/index.html.erb

<% if current_layout == "company" %> # just table
  <%= render "people_table" %>
<% else %>
  <h1>People controller</h3>
  <%= render @people %>
<% end %>
```

Projects template:

```
# views/projects/index.html.erb

<% if current_layout == "company" %> # just table
  <%= render "projects_table" %>
<% else %>
  <h1>Projects controller</h3>
  <%= render @projects %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just for clearness... Why nested layouts? You can always use common layouts, but then you have to repeat "application" layout (with doc tags, scripts, meta tags and other stuff). Nested layouts help you avoid this and DRY.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the rails guides, specifically [routing from the outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

However rails can handle this, your route would be setup in the following way:

```
resources :company do
       resource :projects
       resource :people
end
```

I assume you already have all your CRUD actions setup, then this would work. However do note, it will change your named routes.

i.e

if you were calling

```
projects_path
```

in your views, they will now become:

```
company_projects_path
```

You can see a full list of routes with the command

```
rake routes
```

Comment: Please re-read the question. This is about views, not routing.

Comment: @LoganSerman. For cases like that i use nested layouts. Do you want some details?

Comment: If you want. I'm going to try it out in a bit. If you'd like to give me an example or something, that would help. Up to you :) @ValeryKvon